# Python 3.5 on Windows10 - unable to install cx_freeze - 'cxfreeze-postinstall' does not exist

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to install cx_freeze on python, and its just doesn't seem to work. I've tried both through pip in the command line (python -m pip install cx_freeze) and through pycharm community add packages.

At first it gave the notorious unable to find vcvarsall.bat - but I installed visual studios latest with all the c++ compilers.

Now it gives another error message - cxfreeze-postinstall does not exist:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCSEl.png)

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I tried installing the win32 version - and it worked... Have no idea why, since my computer is a 64bit OS with a 64bit processor, and I've only installed 64bit version of stuff until now.

---

UPDATE: well, the cx_freeze installs, but I still can't manage to get an executable file. I think maybe this module/package is not compatible with python 3.5 - I will later try it on 3.4 and see if it works.

UPDATE_2.0: Works great on Python 3.4 - so I guess there's some problem with the package compatibility with Python 3.5